# Swift 2 error handling - callback and image saving with Parse

Tags: parse-platform, error-handling, swift2

I have tried the conversion tools to update these few lines of code, but unfortunately the process did not caught up these two errors.

Could you help me to understand if I need to introduce the do { and error handling? (I am new to swift!).

The error message I receive is the following: "Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled"

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidAppear(animated)
```

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(result: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

```
self.posts = result as? [Post] ?? []

  // 1
  for post in self.posts {
  // 2
    let data = post.imageFile?.getData()  --> this is where I get the error message
  // 3
    post.image = UIImage(data: data!, scale:1.0)
  }

  self.tableview.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insted of this: `let data = post.imageFile?.getData()`

Use this instead:

```
do
{
    try let data = post.imageFile?.getData()
}
catch
{
    print("Error: \(error)")
    //Handle the error instead of print probably
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It created a new issue on the 'data':                                                    for post in self.posts {
        do {
          let data = try post.imageFile?.getData()
        }
          
        catch
        {
          print("Error: \(error)")
          //Handle the error instead of print probably
        
        }
        post.image = UIImage(data: data!, scale:1.0)  --> Use of unresolved identified 'data' or we have just defined it with the let..
      }
      
      self.tableview.reloadData()
    }
  }